# I need help making sure that user input is an integer and greater than 0

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I've been trying to get this right for a while now, and it seems that something is not working out right because the code keeps accepting invalid values.

```
package main;

import java.util.Scanner;


import tabla.TablaDeVerdad;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inicializador = 1;
        int contador = 1;
        TablaDeVerdad tabla;

        while(inicializador == 1){
            System.out.println("Escoja un número de variables mayor que cero:");
            int input;
            while(!entrada.hasNextInt() || entrada.nextInt() <= 0){
                System.out.println("Error, use un numero que sea mayor que cero:");
                entrada.next();
            }
            input = entrada.nextInt();
            tabla = new TablaDeVerdad(input);
            System.out.println(tabla.getCantidadDeNúmeros());
            inicializador = 0;

        }
    }

}
```

My issue is with these lines:

```
System.out.println("Escoja un número de variables mayor que cero:");
        int input;
        while(!entrada.hasNextInt() || entrada.nextInt() <= 0){
            System.out.println("Error, use un numero que sea mayor que cero:");
            entrada.next();
        }
        input = entrada.nextInt();
        tabla = new TablaDeVerdad(
```

Whenever I run it gives me this as output:
Escoja un número de variables mayor que cero:
0
Error, use un numero que sea mayor que cero:
0
0
Error, use un numero que sea mayor que cero:
0
0
Error, use un numero que sea mayor que cero:
1
1
1
3

When it is always supposed to give the error message if the input is zero and it should also not require to have a number greater than 0 used as input more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand Spanish, but this is one of the way you can make sure that user input is **an integer and greater than 0**

```
....
int input; 
String inputStr = entrada.nextLine();

while(inputStr.replaceAll("\\D","").length() != inputStr.length() || Integer.parseInt(inputStr) <= 0){
    System.out.println("Error, use un numero que sea mayor que cero:");
    inputStr= entrada.nextLine();
}
input = Integer.parseInt(inputStr);
....
```

Comment: Thanks, I really didn't want to do it in Spanish but I have no choice, the people I'm working with don't know English.

Comment: you are welcome. Actually it doesn't really matter, the code is still understandable :)

Comment: I made some changes in `while` condition so that input like `12ab`, `a123` are also invalid